# string split and interchange the position of string in R

Tags: r

I have a vector called myvec. I would like to split it at `_` and interchange the position. What would be the simplest way to do this?

`myvec <- c("08AD09144_NACC022453", "08AD8245_NACC657970")`

Result I want:

`NACC022453_08AD09144, NACC657970_08AD8245`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex capturing data in two groups and interchanging them using back reference.

```
myvec <- c("A1_B1", "B2_C1", "D1_A2")

sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)', '\\2_\\1', myvec)
#[1] "B1_A1" "C1_B2" "A2_D1"
```

Comment: In my actual data it is doing `c(\"NACC022453_08AD09144\", \"08AD8245_NACC657970\")`. How do I remove `\\`?

Comment: @New_to_R Update your post with your actual data and actual expected output. Maybe you need `sub('"(\\w+)_(\\w+)"', '\\2_\\1', myvec)` ?

Comment: My original answer still works for your updated question. `sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)', '\\2_\\1', myvec)` returns `#[1] "NACC022453_08AD09144" "NACC657970_08AD8245"` which is same as your expected output. What do you get?

Comment: I am getting `c(\"NACC022453_08AD09144\", \"08AD8245_NACC657970\")`. This is what I did `sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)', '\\2_\\1', covarAA_ADC1_2[2])`

Comment: Are you using data from your post or using some different data? What is `covarAA_ADC1_2` ?

Comment: These are the column values from dataframe.

Comment: Try with double brackets. `covarAA_ADC1_2[[2]]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
sapply(strsplit(myvec, "_"), function(x) paste(x[2], x[1], sep = "_"))
#[1] "NACC022453_08AD09144" "NACC657970_08AD8245"
```